# Building Web Apps using MongoDB and ASP.NET MVC, Should I Use C# Drivers or Javascript Driver

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, mongodb

I am developing asp.net mvc web app with MongoDB as the data storage.

I want to know others opinion about what drivers to use.

Should I use C# drivers which is supported by community?

Or, should I go to use Javascript driver which is supported by Mongo. How stable is javascript driver?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C# driver is very close to being a 1.0 release and is now supported by 10Gen. Known bugs submitted to the [JIRA](http://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP) Are usually fixed very quickly. There is also a very active [discussion group](http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-csharp?pli=1) which is closely monitored and will usually get your questions answered same day

I would say it is pretty safe to start using the C# driver in production if you are on .Net 3.0 or greater. You may still experience a few breaking changes until version 1.0 is reached but it is usually nothing major and there is always fair warning.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use the JS driver client-side. It will open up your mongo server to potential hacks.

The official C# driver is very stable now. I tried some of the community drivers a while ago and they were too buggy to use.

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Language+Center

Answer (score -1):

To my mind I'd never use any JavaScript driver for a database connection.  I'd always want to keep all my data access within the c# code and away from the UI.

Comment: Javascript can be run server side.